# Is proper practice to use introspection in this example?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is proper practice to use introspection in this example?

I'm in a `UITableView` datasource method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, and I'm checking for the type of the data source objects, in order to decide which `UITableViewCell` subclass to use.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   ....
        id object = [[self getDataSource:tableView] objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];

        if ( [object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] || 
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


        } else if ([object isMemberOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
            cell = [[[CMAutocompleteTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier andAutocompleteTextField:object] autorelease];


        } else if ([object isMemberOfClass:[NSDate class]]) {
            cell = [[[CMDateTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier andTextView:object] autorelease];

       } else {
                cell = [[[CMAutocompleteTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier andAutocompleteTextField:field] autorelease];

            }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: By using the same reuse identifier on all the cells you'll break cell recycling or just get the wrong type of cell when you deque. Each cell type needs a unique identifier.

Comment: Nostalgia - `autorelease` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's technically ok (with the change to `isMemberOfClass:` as Josh pointed out).

It's debatable, if it's good style. Does the same tableview really show items of those different classes next to each other? If there are several tableviews, using separate methods/delegates might be more appropriate.

Also, I think you could improve on your method naming. `getDataSource` is discouraged - "get" has quite a special meaning and is rarely used (for example, in `getBytes` on `NSData`). Also you want to get rid of "and" which is just noise.

Finally, is there any reason not to switch to ARC today?

Comment: Yes it's the same tableView. About ARC: what if you have a huge project with a lot of manual memory management code. If I switch to ARC, do I need to change all old code?

Comment: While you could start with using ARC only for new code, the transition of old cold is well worth it. If you didn't do any fancy things, Xcode's conversion tool will do it (almost) completely perfect for you. Although I think I was rather good at manual memory management, I've never looked back for a second. It reduces code size and noise, removes chances of bugs, and I suspect the code is even better optimizable be the compiler, too. Do it! :)

Answer (score 4):

I can't see any reason not to check the classes of your data objects, but you should use `isKindOfClass:` rather than `isMemberOfClass:`.

The latter checks for an exact match with the class of the receiver, which you're not going to get with the data classes you've got; they're all [class clusters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html). Any given `NSString` you have, e.g., is going to actually be an `__NSCFString`. Likewise for `NSDate` and `NSNumber`.

<sub><sup>Also, you should use ARC.</sup></sub>